# Получить записи по определенному критерию в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ruby

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть коллекция такого типа:

```
{ 
  _id: ObjectId("53f6ea88efd71760ee000002"),
  title: "foo",
  published: "2014-08-22 01:26:21 UTC",
  image: "s3_foo.jpg",
  summary: "foo foo",
  categories: ["foo","bar"],
  content: "foo sting text",
  author: "bar",
  from: ["bar"],
  shop_id: 12279649167164,
}
```

Хочу получить все записи с *shop_id: 12279649167164* и их дату.

```
pry(shop)> @shop_id = "12279649167164"
pry(shop)> a = collection.find( {'shop_id' => @shop_id}, fields: ['published'] }).map {|e| p e}
pry(shop)> []
```

Не пойму, в чем проблема. 
Использую Ruby 2.1.2 и mongo-ruby-driver

Comment: Вроде решил, вот таким способом: 
 
@shop_id = [12279649167164]
time = co.find( {'url_id' => {'$all' => @url_id}}, fields: ['published']).map {|e| p e}

Comment: или просто time = co.find( {'url_id' => @url_id}}, fields: ['published']).map {|e| p e}

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, что вы задаете в качестве критерия поиска строку

```
@shop_id = "12279649167164"
```

Однако в документе MongoDB лежит число

```
shop_id: 12279649167164
```

Ваше условие сработает, если в переменную `@shop_id` вы поместите число

```
@shop_id = 12279649167164
```

Либо приведете строку к числу

```
@shop_id = "12279649167164".to_i
```